# 03/08/2015 was unexpected at this time batch script error

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

First, I should probably mention the context for my code, which is that it was designed to check whether the automatic maintenance task on my computer (or as Windows refers to it, "Regular Maintenance") had been started yet on the same day (if so, the last run date and time would match the date this code was run on and the time would be 12:00:00pm) and if it had finished already (if so, the task's Status would be "Ready" rather than "Running".

The code would then store the value of each of the three checks (0 for success, 1 for failure) in a variable called %maintenance completion%, which I would use later to decide whether to continue with the next section of code, or whether I should loop back until all the conditions are true.

```
FOR /f "tokens=4" %%A IN ('schtasks /query /v /fo list /tn "Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\Regular Maintenance" ^| findstr /c:"Last Run Time:"') DO set last_maintenance_date=%%A
FOR /f "tokens=5" %%A IN ('schtasks /query /v /fo list /tn "Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\Regular Maintenance" ^| findstr /c:"Last Run Time:"') DO set last_maintenance_time=%%A
FOR /f "tokens=2" %%A IN ('schtasks /query /v /fo list /tn "Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\Regular Maintenance" ^| findstr /c:"Status:"') DO set maintenance_status=%%A
FOR /f "tokens=1" %%A IN ('date /t') DO set current_date=%%A
IF /i %maintenance_date% EQU %current_date% (echo date_success & set maintenance_completion=0) ELSE (echo date_fail & set maintenance_completion=1) & set maintenance_completion
IF /i %maintenance_time% EQU 12:00:00 (echo time_success & set maintenance_completion=%maintenance_completion%0) ELSE (echo time_fail & set maintenance_completion=%maintenance_completion%1) & set maintenance_completion
IF /i %maintenance_status% EQU Ready (echo status_success & set maintenance_completion=%maintenance_completion%0) ELSE (echo status_fail & set maintenance_completion=%maintenance_completion%1) & set maintenance_completion
IF %maintenance_completion% EQU 000 (echo success) ELSE (echo %maintenance_completion%)
```

When I run this code in an elevated command prompt window (with %%A being adjusted to %A), then the code runs fine and produces the results that I would normally expect:

```
C:\Windows\system32>FOR /f "tokens=4" %A IN ('schtasks /query /v /fo list /tn "M
icrosoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\Regular Maintenance" ^| findstr /c:"Last Run Time
:"') DO set last_maintenance_date=%A

C:\Windows\system32>set last_maintenance_date=01/08/2015

C:\Windows\system32>FOR /f "tokens=5" %A IN ('schtasks /query /v /fo list /tn "M
icrosoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\Regular Maintenance" ^| findstr /c:"Last Run Time
:"') DO set last_maintenance_time=%A

C:\Windows\system32>set last_maintenance_time=21:16:52

C:\Windows\system32>FOR /f "tokens=2" %A IN ('schtasks /query /v /fo list /tn "M
icrosoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\Regular Maintenance" ^| findstr /c:"Status:"') DO
 set maintenance_status=%A

C:\Windows\system32>set maintenance_status=Ready

C:\Windows\system32>FOR /f "tokens=1" %A IN ('date /t') DO set current_date=%A

C:\Windows\system32>set current_date=03/08/2015

C:\Windows\system32>IF /i %maintenance_date% EQU %current_date% (echo date_succe
ss & set maintenance_completion=0) ELSE (echo date_fail & set maintenance_comple
tion=1)
date_fail

C:\Windows\system32>set maintenance_completion
maintenance_completion=1

C:\Windows\system32>IF /i %maintenance_time% EQU 12:00:00 (echo time_success & s
et maintenance_completion=%maintenance_completion%0) ELSE (echo time_fail & set
maintenance_completion=%maintenance_completion%1)
time_fail

C:\Windows\system32>set maintenance_completion
maintenance_completion=11

C:\Windows\system32>IF /i %maintenance_status% EQU Ready (echo status_success &
set maintenance_completion=%maintenance_completion%0) ELSE (echo status_fail & s
et maintenance_completion=%maintenance_completion%1)
status_success

C:\Windows\system32>set maintenance_completion
maintenance_completion=110

C:\Windows\system32>IF %maintenance_completion% EQU 000 (echo success) ELSE (ech
o %maintenance_completion%)
110
```

However, when I run it as a batch script, I get this error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>FOR /F "tokens=4" %A IN ('schtasks /query /v /fo list /tn "M
icrosoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\Regular Maintenance" | findstr /c:"Last Run Time:
"') DO set last_maintenance_date=%A

C:\Windows\system32>set last_maintenance_date=01/08/2015

C:\Windows\system32>FOR /F "tokens=5" %A IN ('schtasks /query /v /fo list /tn "M
icrosoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\Regular Maintenance" | findstr /c:"Last Run Time:
"') DO set last_maintenance_time=%A

C:\Windows\system32>set last_maintenance_time=21:16:52

C:\Windows\system32>FOR /F "tokens=2" %A IN ('schtasks /query /v /fo list /tn "M
icrosoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\Regular Maintenance" | findstr /c:"Status:"') DO
set maintenance_status=%A

C:\Windows\system32>set maintenance_status=Ready

C:\Windows\system32>FOR /F "tokens=1" %A IN ('date /t') DO set current_date=%A

C:\Windows\system32>set current_date=03/08/2015
**03/08/2015 was unexpected at this time.**

C:\Windows\system32>**IF /i  EQU 03/08/2015** (echo date_success & set maintenance_c
ompletion=0) ELSE (echo date_fail & set maintenance_completion=1) & set maintena
nce_completion
```

In addition, if I replace the first variable on the line that fails (%maintenance_date%) with its equivalent string literal (01/08/2015), then that line runs fine, and then the next line fails due to the same problem with the first variable on that line (%maintenance_time%).

This leads me to believe that for some reason, runnning the code as a batch file causes some error to be thrown due to having variables as the first item in an IF statement, but I'm unsure as to exactly what the problem is or how I can fix it?

Comment: ...not a solution for the problem, but a recommendation for improvement: you could combine the first two `FOR` lines to one to read the date and time token at once: `FOR /f "tokens=4-5" %%A IN ('schtasks /query /v /fo list /tn "Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\Regular Maintenance" ^| findstr /c:"Last Run Time:"') DO (set last_maintenance_date=%%A&set last_maintenance_time=%%B)`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion, I'll put it in and double check that that section of new code runs with no errors :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out what was wrong! It was a syntax error on my part, as I wrote `IF /i %maintenance_date%` and `IF /i %maintenance_time%` rather than `%last_maintenance_date%` and `%last_maintenance_time%` !

Once again, thanks for your suggestion though [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl).